# Traps handling (SNMP possible?) to generate email/alerts in context with Ejabberd

Tags: erlang, snmp, ejabberd, nagios, net-snmp

I have come across a lot of tools to monitor Linux servers which could generate alerts as well when the CPU usage goes alarmingly high, or the disk space goes very low etc.

However, in terms of Ejabberd I couldn’t find an exisiting module which could do something similar. I am particularly looking to receive alerts pertaining to mnesia getting overloaded, space availability etc. and other basic parameters worth monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Exometer](https://github.com/Feuerlabs/exometer). It can report via SNMP. It doesn't come with the monitoring you're talking about out of the box but you should be able to configure it to report on whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

SNMP support comes standard with Erlang. You should have a look at Erlang/OTP [os_mon](http://erlang.org/doc/man/os_mon_app.html). Depending on your needs, it may do what you want out of the box.

Comment: I looked into os_mon and executed some disk space utilisation commands as well. Seems, it fetches OS related data.

However, i am looking to get Ejabberd specific parameters. Mnesia space utilisation would be great if achievable.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can totally configure SNMP to expose the data you want from Erlang. For example, you tried the OS Mon MIB but there is other Mibs available like OTP MIB. Mnesia info are not exposed in the OTP mib but as data is available through Mnesia info, you can expose it in mib. Here is a tutorial: https://erlangcentral.org/wiki/index.php?title=SNMP_Quick_Start